# Arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I seem to be going around in circles on something I know is really easy. But I must be having a bad day.

I want to populate a 2d array dynamically.

If I do it statically like this:

```
arrChartValues = new Array(['Q1', 20], ['Q2', 10], ['Q3', 30]);
```

But I want it to be in a loop inserting lots of pairs of values.

Comment: Do you want to know how to loop over multiple axes, set elements of the 2D array, set elements of the 1D arrays or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a= [];
for (i=0; i<20; i++){
  a[i]= ['q'+i, i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For example:

```
arrChartValues = [];

for (var i=1;i<10;i++)
   arrChartValue.push(["Q" + i,i*10])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add new items to an existing array, use the [`push` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) like this:

```
arrChartValues = new Array(['Q1', 20], ['Q2', 10], ['Q3', 30]);
arrChartValues.push(['Q4', 40]);
```

Comment: I don't know how many data pairs there will be so I need to build the array dynamically in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrChartValues = [];
```

then in your loop:

```
arrChartValues.push(['Q1', 20]);
```

which adds the value to your array