# Google App Script arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

I'm working on Google Script and I'm testing different ways to create two dimensions arrays.
I have created an array like this:

```
  var codes = new Array(6);
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  codes[i] = new Array(4);
  }
  codes[0][0]="x"; 
  codes[0][1]="x"; 
  codes[0][2]="x"; 
  codes[0][3]="x";
  codes[1][0]="x";
  codes[1][1]="x";
  codes[1][2]="x"; 
  codes[1][3]="x";
  codes[2][0]="x";
  codes[2][1]="x";
  codes[2][2]="x";
  codes[2][3]="x";
  codes[3][0]="x";
  codes[3][1]="x";
  codes[3][2]="x";
  codes[3][3]="x";
  codes[4][0]="x";
  codes[4][1]="x";
  codes[4][2]="x";
  codes[4][3]="x";
  codes[5][0]="x";
  codes[5][1]="x";
  codes[5][2]="x";
  codes[5][3]="x";
```

And it is working fine.

I read following links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086248/arrays-javascript), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427599/how-to-create-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-javascript?lq=1).

But when I do it like this:

```
var codes = new Array(6);
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  codes[i] = new Array(4);
  }
codes[0]=["x","x","x","x"];
codes[1]=["x","x","x","x"];
codes[2]=["x","x","x","x"];
codes[3]=["x","x","x","x"];
codes[4]=["x","x","x","x"];
codes[5]=["x","x","x","x"];
```

It didn't work, so I tried like this:

```
var codes = new Array([["x","x","x","x"],["x","x","x","x"],["x","x","x","x"],["x","x","x","x"],["x","x","x","x"],["x","x","x","x"]]);
```

it didn't work either.

When the code don't work, I get no error, just no display of the values.

What am I doing wrong? It looks to be the same code and the two not working ways are recommended in many documentations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) says that there is no need to use `new Array()`.
For simplicity, readability and execution speed, use literal method ex:

`var animals = ["cat", "rabbit"];`

Reason why your code was not working is that you're equaling `codes` inside the loop and after end of loop scope 'codes' is getting only the last set array. Instead you should push those arrays to `codes`.

```js
var codes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  codes.push([i]);
}
console.log(codes)
codes[0]=["x","x","x","x"];
codes[1]=["x","x","x","x"];
codes[2]=["x","x","x","x"];
codes[3]=["x","x","x","x"];
codes[4]=["x","x","x","x"];
codes[5]=["x","x","x","x"];
```

Comment: I didn't saw that new Array() was a bad solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, two for loops to create the double array:

```
var codes = [], // Initiate as array, in Javascript this is actually fastre than using new (I don't know any cases you should use new)
    rows = 6,
    columns = 6;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    codes.push([]); // Initiate 
    for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        codes[i][j] = 'x';
    }
}
```

Other idea, pre-initiate an array with the correct columns then copy:

```
var arrTemp = [],
    codes = [],
    rows = 6,
    columns = 6;

for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    arrTemp[i] = 'x';

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    codes.push( arrTemp.slice(0) ); // If you just push the array without slice it will make a reference to it, not copy
```

Other way to pre-initiate the array with 'x's:

```
arrTemp = Array.apply(null, Array(columns)).map(function () {return 'x'});
```